# Код некорректно считывает данные из файла (C++)

Tags: c++, классы, fstream

Файл состоит из нескольких строк, в строках слова, записанные через пробел(abc sd fdf). Нужно считать только первую строку.

```
ifstream file("input.txt");
string* sample = (string*)calloc(1000000, sizeof(string));
char check_for_endline;
int sample_word_count = 0;
while (file >> sample[sample_word_count])
{
    file.get(check_for_endline);
    if (check_for_endline == '\n')
    {
        break;
    }
    sample_word_count++;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Видите ли, `string` — *класс*, т.е. со своим конструктором, каковой при сугубо "сишном" выделении памяти через `calloc` никто и не подумает вызывать. Так что у вас не массив строк, а массив кусков памяти размером со строку...

Раз уж С++, то попробуйте так:

```
ifstream file("input.txt");
vector<string> sample;
char check_for_endline;
string s;
while (file >> s)
{
    sample.push_back(s);
    file.get(check_for_endline);
    if (check_for_endline == '\n')
    {
        break;
    }
}
for(auto s: sample) cout << s << endl;
```

Даже выделение через `new` лучше не делать...

Comment: спасибо за подсказку, с векторами программа стала ещё и быстрее работать

Answer (score 0):

Я разобрался, не уверен почему, но для классов динамическая память выделяется только через конструкцию: `string *sample = new string[1000000]`.

Comment: Память можно выделить динамически и другими способами, главное в том, что оператор `new` еще и вызывает конструкторы для всех этих объектов, а не только выделяет память для них.